# You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I have 2 plugins installed(redmine_backlogs and redmine_ldap_sync), but after upgrade of redmine_ldap_sync from 2.0.0 to 2.0.1 a Gemfile was added.

Here the backlogs's Gemfile https://github.com/backlogs/redmine_backlogs/blob/v1.0.2/Gemfile
and ldap sync's Gemfile https://github.com/thorin/redmine_ldap_sync/blob/2.0.1/Gemfile

In both cases, the **simplecov** is in the test group. I tried to run

```
bundle install --without development test
```

but I got this error:

```
You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements. 
You specified: simplecov (>= 0) and simplecov (~> 0.6)
```

This does not seem to make sense. Is there a way to bypass it without editing the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All Gemfiles from plugins are merged with general one. Just delete `simplecov (>= 0)` statement in one of the plugins Gemfile. It is not criminal or illegal.

Comment: For me, I delete Gemfile, then call `bundle init` to re-generate it, then it's fine.